# C++ std::priority_queue is about 4 times slower compared to the same functionality with sorted array. Why this would be?

Tags: c++, queue, std

I am experimenting with using priority queue to compare its performance to sorted array of objects. Based on my test results, priority queue is about 4 times slower. The test task is the following: we have a fixed number of struct elements, with their values and indexes. We then on each step, in a loop, take out the element with smallest value, and add to the input a new element with randomly chosen value.

Here's my source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <functional>
#include <queue>

#define FIXED_SIZE 14400

struct element
{
    int index;
    int value;
};

int compare (const void * _a, const void * _b)
{
    element *a = (element *)_a;
    element *b = (element *)_b;

    if (a->value < b->value) return -1;
    if (a->value > b->value) return 1;

    return 0;
}

void runRandomCyclePQ(const long limit)
{
    printf ("Priority Queue\n");

    long cnt = 0;

    const int size = FIXED_SIZE;

    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int,int>> queue;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        element el;
        el.value = rand();
        el.index = i;

        queue.push (std::make_pair(-el.value, el.index));
    }

    int curr_index = size;

    while (cnt < limit)
    {
        if ((cnt & 1023) == 0)
        {
            auto & el = queue.top();

            printf ("%d, %d\n", -el.first, el.second);
        }

        queue.pop();

        int v = rand();

        element e;
        e.index = ++curr_index;
        e.value = v;

        queue.push (std::make_pair(-e.value, e.index));

        cnt++;
    }
}

void runRandomCycle(const long limit)
{
    printf ("Sorted array\n");

    long cnt = 0;

    const int size = FIXED_SIZE;

    element * array = new element [size]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i].value = rand();
        array[i].index = i;
    }

    int curr_index = size;

    qsort (array, size, sizeof(element), compare);

    while (cnt < limit)
    {
        if ((cnt & 1023) == 0)
        {
            auto el = array[0];

            printf ("%d, %d\n", el.value, el.index);
        }

        int v = rand();

        if (v < array[1].value)
        {
            array[0].value = v;
            array[0].index = ++curr_index;
        }
        else 
        {
            int idx = 1;
            for (; idx < size; idx++)
            {
                if (v < array[idx].value) break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < idx - 1; i++)
            {
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
            }
            array[idx - 1].value = v;
            array[idx - 1].index = ++curr_index;
        }

        cnt++;
    }

    delete[] array;
}

int main ()
{
    int t = time (NULL);

    runRandomCycle (1000000000L);

    int t2 = time(NULL);

    printf ("took %d sec\n", t2 - t);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's my output:

```
~/Developer/priority_queue$ make -B
g++ -o priority -std=c++17 -Wall -O2 main.cpp -lm
~/Developer/priority_queue$ ./priority
Sorted array
took 7 sec
~/Developer/priority_queue$ make -B
g++ -o priority -std=c++17 -Wall -O2 main.cpp -lm
~/Developer/priority_queue$ ./priority
Priority Queue
took 29 sec
```

I verified that runRandomCycle() and runRandomCyclePQ() output is identical.

With this results in mind, why would I be ever using priority queue? My thinking was that it uses some tree-like structure such as minheap under the hood, which speeds things up, but in pactice it's way slower compared to the straightforward sorted array version. Am I missing something?

Update: I increased FIXED_SIZE 100-fold to 14400, this had no significant change when comparing performance:

```
~/Developer/priority_queue$ ./priority
Sorted array
took 8 sec
~/Developer/priority_queue$ make -B
g++ -o priority -std=c++17 -Wall -O2 main.cpp -lm
~/Developer/priority_queue$ ./priority
Priority Queue
took 45 sec
```

Comment: For one thing, you're not doing the same thing in the two versions. The `vector` version does not do a pop. It is doing a replace because it essentially overwrites the top of stack with the new one.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You mean the array version? No, I am not always replacing the first element. I am taking away the 1st element but I am inserting new element into the right position to keep array sorted.

Comment: Your second algorithm isn't correct. It doesn't add the same number of elements as the first one. The code executed if the `if` test is successful is wrong. Fix that and re-rest.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I just updated the source to print the output every 1024 elements. It's identical (just as I mentioned earlier) between the two methods - in case you believe I am doing something wrong in the 2nd algorithm.